# What If the SPF Record Doesn't Exists?

Tags: email, dns, spam, spf

I would like to know whether the mail receiving server will reject the mail if it requests a SPF record check but no SPF record exists in the DNS server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on the setup of the spam check in the receiving server.

Some spam filters use a default SPF record, when the sending domain does not specify one (e.g. `v=spf1 a/24 mx/24 ptr ?all`).

So it would always be a good idea to specify a `SPF` record for any domain to avoid problems with such a default record. Even if the domain is not used to send mail, it's still a good idea to specify a record to indicate this (e.g. `v=spf1 -all`).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But what if the spam filter does not provide a default SPF record and the receiving server receives no SPF record?

Comment: In that case there will be no SPF check performed on the receiving server.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much for your help!